# How to create .netstandard nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to create nuget package using my .netstandard 1.2 dll.
I can't install this nuget in UWP project because of error:

> Package ZZZ is not compatible with uap10.0.14393
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393). Package ZZZ 1.0.0 supports: net
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

What and where should be configured to add support for example for UWP?

When I reference my .netstandard dll in UWP project directly, everything works fine.

Comment: sounds like your nuget package is corrupted. Try open the .nuget file, its a zip. Check the `lib` folder there should be a  standard1.2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the nuget package?

- Try upgrade to the latest nuget.exe and pack with that
- Alternativly use the built in packing that is part of dotnet core csproj file and visual studio 2017/msbuild (and dotnet pack) by creating a brand new netstandard project and adding [nuget properties in the csproj file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties)
- [Check the version compatability of UWP and netstandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) and consider changing to netstandard 2 and UWP 10.0.16299 as lots of these gremlins have been resolved

Comment: I use the newest version of nuget.exe. Lib folder contains standard 1.2 folder. Package is creating manually or by pack function in visual studio. Can't change version to netstandard 2 because I have to use this package in WinRT project also.

Comment: To be able to give a more detailed answer we will need more information. Try and create the smallest possible reproduction of the issue with 2 empty projects, pack one and reference the nupkg from the uwp one, otherwise it could be something else unrelated.

Comment: You're right. The problem is probably somewhere else for example in project structure. Thank you!